# MySQL installer only installs the Workbench, not the server

Tags: mysql

I have successfully downloaded the workbench and it works fine, however, in my `C:/ProgramFiles/MySQL` folder, only the workbench is there, and not the server itself. I can't add MySQL to my PATH, nor can I run any local server.

I downloaded it from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/, and I chose the 420.6M version for Windows, and ran it normally. Is it actually installed?

Comment: You can close this question

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled MySQL workbench and re ran the installer and it worked. The reason why, I'm guessing, is because I installed only the workbench awhile ago. When the new installer saw I had the workbench installed, it just stopped checking to install other products like MySQL server.